# Run Python binaries under Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyside, pyinstaller

I compiled my PySide application to both x32 and x64 mode and it's work under Windows 7+. However I found that the application can't start under Windows XP.

Should I use some tricks in spec-file additionally?

Current PyInstaller script shown below in app.spec file:

> pyinstaller src/app.spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import os
import platform

from PySide import QtCore


onefile = False
console = False

platform_name = platform.system().lower()
app_name = {'linux': 'app',
            'darwin': 'app',
            'windows': 'app.exe'}[platform_name]

# Include imageformats plugins
plugins=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(QtCore.__file__), "plugins\\imageformats")
static_files = Tree(plugins, 'plugins\\imageformats')
static_files += [('app.ico', 'src\\app.ico', 'DATA')]

# Analyze sources
a = Analysis(['src\\app.py'],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources'],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

if onefile:
    exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, a.datas, name=app_name,
        debug=False, strip=None, upx=True, console=console, icon='src/app.ico', version='src/app.ver')
else:
    exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, exclude_binaries=True, name=app_name, debug=False,
        strip=None, upx=True, console=console, icon='src/app.ico', version='src/app.ver')
    coll = COLLECT(exe, a.binaries, static_files, a.zipfiles, a.datas, strip=None, upx=True, name='app')
```

Comment: A) you _really_ shouldn't be using XP. It is no longer supported by MS and using it is very dangerous. B) can't you re compile with older versions that did support XP?

Comment: I found that when I run under PyCharm everything is OK under WinXP too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the core problems related to this issue:

> > - Don't need to use `print()` at the sources, more detail here - [PyInstaller packaged application works fine in Console mode, crashes in Window mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429924/pyinstaller-packaged-application-works-fine-in-console-mode-crashes-in-window-m)
> > - After that I catched issue with `import requests` and solution here - http://flashmaestro.blogspot.com/2015/04/pyinstaller-solution-about.html