# Error during compiling with PyInstaller under Windows XP (not English)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, pyinstaller

I have next `app.spec` file - [Run Python binaries under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049372/run-python-binaries-under-windows-xp) and try to compile with PyInstaller under Windows XP (Russian localization)

I got follow error:

```
1763 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\main.py", line 88, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\main.py", line 46, in run_buil
d
    PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1911, in main
    config = configure.get_config(kw.get('upx_dir'))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\configure.py", line 146, in ge
t_config
    find_PYZ_dependencies(config)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\configure.py", line 116, in fi
nd_PYZ_dependencies
    a.analyze_r('pyi_importers')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 16
6, in analyze_r
    newnms = self.analyze_one(name, nm, imptyp, level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 22
7, in analyze_one
    mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 29
9, in doimport
    mod = parent.doimport(nm)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\modules.py", line 130,
in doimport
    mod = self.subimporter.getmod(nm)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\impdirector.py", line 1
39, in getmod
    mod = owner.getmod(nm)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\owner.py", line 127, in
 getmod
    mod = self._modclass()(nm, pth, co)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\modules.py", line 78, i
n __init__
    self.scancode()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\modules.py", line 99, i
n scancode
    self.binaries = _resolveCtypesImports(self.binaries)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 328, in
 _resolveCtypesImports
    cpath = find_library(os.path.splitext(cbin)[0])
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\util.py", line 54, in find_library
    fname = os.path.join(directory, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 34: ordinal
 not in range(128)
```

What should I patch? This error reproducible also under Windows 7 with Russian localization

---

**PS.** It's not the same issue, but maybe can be some advise - [Run Python binaries under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049372/run-python-binaries-under-windows-xp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by avoiding using any print statements in the application and changing `print` to `log` methods