# Issue with import QT files in PyInstaller 3.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, pyinstaller

I have a `app.spec`-file shown with details here [Run Python binaries under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049372/run-python-binaries-under-windows-xp)

when I built a project with `PyInstaller 2.1` I saw only:

- PyQt4.QtCore.pyd
- PySide.QtCore.pyd
- PySide.QtGui.pyd
- PySide.QtNetwork.pyd
- PySide.QtWebKit.pyd

Now, after building with `PyInstaller 3.0` I saw additionally:

- qtcore4.dll
- qtgui4.dll
- qtnetwork4.dll
- qtopengl4.dll
- qtsvg4.dll
- qtwebkit4.dll
- qtxml4.dll

What is correct fix for avoiding adding `QT-libs` and importing original `PySide` libraries only?