# Print output from python to C# application

Tags: python, redirect, output

I have made a C# app which calls a python script.
C# app uses Process object to call python script.
I also have redirected the sub-process standard output so I can process the output from python script.

But the problem is:
The output(via print function) from python will always arrive at once when the script terminates.
I want the output to arrive in real time while script running.

I can say I have tried almost all of method can get from google, like add  flush of sys.out, redirect sysout in python, C# event driven message receiving or just using while to wait message etc,.

[How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)

[PyInstaller packaged application works fine in Console mode, crashes in Window mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429924/pyinstaller-packaged-application-works-fine-in-console-mode-crashes-in-window-m)

I am very wondering that like PyCharm or other python IDE, they run python script inside, but they can print the output one by one **without hacking original python script**, how they do that?

The python version is 2.7.
Hope to have advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just use very stupid but working method to resolve it:

using thread to periodically flush the sys.out, the code piece is like this:

```
import sys
import os
import threading
import time


run_thread = False


def flush_print():
    while run_thread:
       # print 'something'
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

in **main** function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=flush_print)
    run_thread = True
    thread.start()

    # my big functions with some prints, the function will block until completed

    run_thread = False
    thread.join()
```

Apparently this is ugly, but I have no better method to make work done .